# unable to mount file from k8s pod to host

Tags: kubernetes, mounted-volumes

I want to access file `/opt/e2/router.txt` from the k8s pod `deployment-ricplt-e2term-alpha-54c8f5f7f4-f8s8p` on my host machine in the directory  `/home/ubuntu/pod-share/`.

To achieve the same, I have mounted that with mount name `hostvol`, however my `pod` keeps crashing with `CrashLoopBackOff` error. What could be wrong with the below settings? I don't see the file in my host. I do not get any error in mounting in describe cmd.

Describe cmd output of pod. No mount error.

```
/home/ubuntu/> kubectl descibe pod deployment-ricplt-e2term-alpha-54c8f5f7f4-f8s8p  -n ricplt 
Name:         deployment-ricplt-e2term-alpha-54c8f5f7f4-f8s8p
Namespace:    ricplt
Priority:     0
Node:         vax-shardul/167.254.203.204
Start Time:   Fri, 28 Apr 2023 07:45:58 +0000
Labels:       app=ricplt-e2term-alpha
              pod-template-hash=54c8f5f7f4
              release=r4-e2term
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.0.36
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.36
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/deployment-ricplt-e2term-alpha-54c8f5f7f4
Containers:
  container-ricplt-e2term:
    Container ID:   docker://c227b121e5d37eee79b011d9c3a957971a823cda316098baf4fc898da10fc909
    Image:          offlinereporic.fujitsu.com:5000/e2-term:6.0.1
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:ad47bda057147bd9c55b0f3b50aa0613cf2d03baa380d5093b7a2d27a9bb1609
    Ports:          4561/TCP, 38000/TCP, 36422/SCTP, 8088/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/SCTP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 28 Apr 2023 07:49:10 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 28 Apr 2023 07:49:10 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Liveness:       exec [/bin/sh -c ip=`hostname -i`;export RMR_SRC_ID=$ip;/opt/e2/rmr_probe -h $ip:38000] delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      exec [/bin/sh -c ip=`hostname -i`;export RMR_SRC_ID=$ip;/opt/e2/rmr_probe -h $ip:38000] delay=120s timeout=1s period=60s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment Variables from:
      configmap-ricplt-e2term-env-alpha  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
      SYSTEM_NAME:      SEP
      CONFIG_MAP_NAME:  /etc/config/log-level
      HOST_NAME:         (v1:spec.nodeName)
      SERVICE_NAME:     RIC_E2_TERM
      CONTAINER_NAME:   container-ricplt-e2term
      POD_NAME:         deployment-ricplt-e2term-alpha-54c8f5f7f4-f8s8p (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /data/outgoing/ from vol-shared (rw)
      /opt/e2/leak.out from hostvol (rw,path="leak.out")
      /opt/e2/router.txt from local-router-file (rw,path="router.txt")
      /tmp/rmr_verbose from local-router-file (rw,path="rmr_verbose")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-9gvzm (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  local-router-file:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      configmap-ricplt-e2term-router-configmap
    Optional:  false
  hostvol:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home/ubuntu/pod-share/
    HostPathType:  
  vol-shared:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pvc-ricplt-e2term-alpha
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-9gvzm:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-9gvzm
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                  Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>              default-scheduler     Successfully assigned ricplt/deployment-ricplt-e2term-alpha-54c8f5f7f4-f8s8p to vax-shardul
  Warning  BackOff    3m9s (x10 over 4m33s)  kubelet, vax-shardul  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulled     2m58s (x5 over 4m35s)  kubelet, vax-shardul  Container image "offlinereporic.fujitsu.com:5000/e2-term:6.0.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2m58s (x5 over 4m35s)  kubelet, vax-shardul  Created container container-ricplt-e2term
  Normal   Started    2m58s (x5 over 4m34s)  kubelet, vax-shardul  Started container container-ricplt-e2term




/home/ubuntu/> kuebctl get pods -A | grep e2t
ricplt        deployment-ricplt-e2term-alpha-54c8f5f7f4-f8s8p              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          6m10s   10.244.0.36       vax-shardul   <none>           <none>
/home/ubuntu/>
```

--- depolyement file contains see "hostvol" config

```
/home/ubuntu/>  kubectl edit deployment deployment-ricplt-e2term-alpha -n ricplt
...........
...........
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/e2/router.txt
          name: local-router-file
          subPath: router.txt
        - mountPath: /tmp/rmr_verbose
          name: local-router-file
          subPath: rmr_verbose
        - mountPath: /opt/e2/leak.out
          name: hostvol                            -------> see this 
          subPath: leak.out
        - mountPath: /data/outgoing/
          name: vol-shared
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      hostname: e2term-alpha
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: secret-offlinereporic-fujitsu-com-5000
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420 
          name: configmap-ricplt-e2term-router-configmap
        name: local-router-file
      - hostPath:
          path: /home/ubuntu/pod-share/
          type: ""
        name: hostvol                                ---------> see this 
      - name: vol-shared
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-ricplt-e2term-alpha
.......
........
```

Comment: Do you know why the container is exiting; have you looked at its logs?  The `hostPath` volume will hide the content that was originally was in the image, which could be causing problems.  Also note that it will bind-mount a directory from the node on which the pod is running – frequently not your local system, and not a consistent node – and depending on why you're trying to get access to your file, it is probably not the right approach.

Comment: there is a log file generated in pod/container  named  "leak.out" i want to save this in my host system so that in case pod restarts i have that file as log in my host.

Comment: On a random node in your cluster, or locally?  Would you have some sort of DaemonSet that's able to collect the data?  Have you figured out why the container is exiting (maybe a permission problem writing the file; again something tricky to maintain with `hostPath` volumes)?

Comment: no there is no demon set to collect the data. it is just a simple container where a log will be generated and i want to keep that logfile in my host home dir.

Comment: Kubernetes pods can't access the filesystems of arbitrary desktop machines outside the cluster.

Comment: this the host machine where k8s is running